# Подсчитать кол-во слов в строке C#

Tags: c#

Нужно в тексте подсчитать количество определенных слов, например:

> Словом можно убить, словом можно спасти.

Нужно посчитать, сколько раз в строке(или тексте) встречается слово "Словом", и записать результат в переменную.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для разделения строки на слова можно воспользоваться методом `Split` и передать в параметре символы для деления.

```
String s = "Словом можно убить, словом можно спасти.";
String sSearch = "словом";

String[] words = s.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' });

int counter = 0;

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (sSearch == word.ToLower())
        counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine(counter);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: А не проще сразу привести строку к нижнему регистру, чем каждый раз дергать в цикле?

Answer (score 2):

А я бы сделал так:

Есть к примеру у нас строка:

```
string str = "Словом можно убить, словом можно спасти.";
```

Нам надо для начала перевести ее в нижний регистр (`ToLower()`), далее разбить на слова. Как на мой взгляд это хорошо делает `Regex.Split` (ибо ему не надо задавать все знаки для "разбития"). Ну и дальше, имея массив всех слов, мы можем сгруппировать их и составить новую коллекцию, которая будет содержать кол-во найденных слов и само слово. Исходя из этого, наша строка будет примерно следующей:

```
var words = Regex.Split(str.ToLower(), @"\W+")
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .Select(s => new {Word = s.Key, Count = s.Count()});
```

Собственно все. Можно теперь смело выводить все, что нам требуется:

```
var count = words.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Word == "словом")?.Count;
```

Если нам не нужно знать о других словах, то можно немного переписать:

```
var words = Regex.Split(str.ToLower(), @"\W+")
    .Where(x => x == "словом")
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .Select(s => new {Word = s.Key, Count = s.Count()})
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Count;
```

* `Select` в данном примере является неким удобством, что бы мы знали и слово и кол-во найденных соответствий. На выходе получим `int?`, который вернет число найденных слов, либо null, если такого слова не найдено.

Ну, если нужно просто кол-во слов, то можно вообще поступить следующим образом:

```
int words = Regex.Split(str.ToLower(), @"\W+").Count(x => x == "словом");
```

Comment: после where groupby уже не нужен. достаточно просто count взят ь

Comment: @Grundy В моих вариантах я для удобства вывожу `Word` и `Count`, без `GroupBy` этого вроде не сделать. Ну а так, ваш вариант добавил в ответ.

Comment: _Select в данном примере является неким удобством, что бы мы знали и слово и кол-во найденных соответствий_ - ты уже знаешь слово, потому что используешь его в where, именно поэтому groupby не нужен: будет всегда только одна группа

Answer (score 1):

Всё предельно просто, ищем количество вхождений подстроки регулярным выражением.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**Метод:**

```
private int countWord(string source, string search)
{
    string pattern = $"\\b{Regex.Escape(search)}\\b";
    return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(source).Count;
}
```

**Применение:**

```
int count = countWord("Словом можно убить, словом можно спасти.", "словом");
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75685/discussion-on-answer-by-digital-core-------c).

Answer (score 1):

Постройте на основе слова регулярку вида `\bслово\b` и посчитайте количество совпадений. `\b` - это граница слова. Слово прогоните через `Regex.Escape`, чтобы экранировать спецсимволы.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

....

string source = "Словом можно убить, словом можно спасти.";
string word = "словом";
int count = Regex.Matches(
    source,
    $"\\b{Regex.Escape(word)}\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Count; // 2
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75675/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash-------c).